# How to setup data fixtures in Google App Engine for Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, fixtures

I would like to have some data fixtures put into data store when my go project is deployed, similar to what can be done in Django. Is it possible? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your are looking for some configuration to put data into datastore, the answer is no. also the python and java versions of appengine don't have such feature.

what i think the django framework for appengine is doing, is the same as you could do.

just write the data you need to the datastore inside your app `init` method
also inside `init` you check if the data is already written.

then any time the app is startet, he checks if it should write some fixture data to datastore, and you can be sure that before first request is processed that its there.